# Add only subsections under current section to the section page in metropolis theme at beginning of sections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, beamer-metropolis

I'd like to add the list of ***all*** subsections in the current section to the section page at the beginning of each section. I am using the metropolis theme. I did some research and found a way to do so by editing the beamer template of section page and add the `beamercolorbox` with `\tableofcontents` and option `[sectionstyle=hide/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]`, as shown below.

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
    {
    \setbeamertemplate{section page}{
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{25em}
            \raggedright
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title}
            \usebeamerfont{section title}
            \insertsectionhead\\[-1ex]
            \usebeamertemplate*{progress bar in section page}
            \par \vskip3pt
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.7\paperwidth, vmode]{}
                \usebeamerfont{subsection in toc}
                \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=hide/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\else%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection title}%
                \usebeamerfont{subsection title}%
                \insertsubsectionhead
            \fi
        \end{minipage}
        \par
        \vspace{\baselineskip}}
        \frame{\subsectionpage}
    }
}
```

However, the line spacing is weird:
[image]

Items are really close to each other. I then found a way to adjust line spacing by doing

```
    \pretocmd{\beamer@subsectionintoc}
    {\vskip2\itemsep}
    {\vfill}
    {}
    {}
```

which causes weird vertical skips before the subsections, like this:
[image]

The first section is normal. But later sections have larger and larger skips, which I think is additional spaces generated by the invisible former (sub)sections, but I do not know how to fix this or if there should be another way to adjust the line spacing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // I'm afraid nobody can copy and run your code, as it misses all relevant parts which precede it. Would be nice, if you can complete your code for the rest of us ;-) // To the right you'll see linkes related to your question. Also don't hesitate to search here, or to click on the tags of your question.